# How do you calculate % CPU and %Memory utilization by VM given the quick stats

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to pull vm guest data from vcenter. By looking at [vcenter guest data](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vm.Summary.QuickStats.html)

I can see some counters as follows:

"summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage" in mhz and "guestMemoryUsage" in MB. Since this number in mHZ, MB how would I calculate the %CPU and %memory utilization by vm?

Comment: What are you pulling the data into?

Comment: @ewwhite, I am using pysphere to pull the data locally. Also, do  you know how to connect to statistics module on vcenter? I couldnt find any docs.

Comment: I do not know. I'd be curious in the solution, but in general, I don't monitor VMs in this manner.